# Difference between 2 apps running a secondary thread for communication and 2 apps using the same communication process

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiprocessing, ipc

I am new in multi-processing. I am creating an app in modern c++ that communicates with PLCs by modbus TCP. Thus, I have created my library to achieve that and I run the communication process on a different thread and the main thread communicates with it by a shared queue and events. It works well.
Now, I would like to design another app that has a different purpose that would sometime run in parallel to the first one. It still needs to communication with the PLCs. Should I also implement it with multithreading, opening a new canal of communication in a thread? Or should I implement some unique communication process and that every executables would connect to via some pipe? What is the difference between the two and is there a logic to use/exclude one of those solutions?

I see advantages in the multi-threading solution:

1. If the client fails, it only affects one program until reconnexion,
2. Shared memory is useful,
3. It is already implemented in my case

But I also see several advantages for the multi-processing approach. One communication client could be used by many apps. Also among them, it appears to be better for optimization.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Look into `select`, `epoll` or Overlapped IO, depending on which is supported by your OS. Any of them will allow you to communicate with one or more modbus devices without needing ANY threads and subsequent message passing and concurrency defense. Haven't messed much with modbus TCP, on a multidrop network multiple modbus masters was not recommended, bordering on a no-no. I believe Modbus TCP is stateless to keep it as close in function to the original serial network variants, so you should exercise caution if you have more than one application controlling the device.

Comment: On Windows platforms, I do this by creating a COM .exe server that does all the interaction with the PLC's.  Any number of clients talk to the PLC by connecting to the .exe server via its COM interface.